# Why browser is asking for a cached file?

Tags: php, apache, caching

I have these directives in my *htaccess*:

```
# BEGIN Compress text files
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
  <filesMatch "\.(css|js|x?html?|php)$">
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Compress text files

# BEGIN Expire headers
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 86400 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 86400 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 86400 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 86400 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 86400 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 86400 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 86400 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 86400 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 86400 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</ifModule>
# END Expire headers

# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, private"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600, private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Cache-Control Headers

# BEGIN Turn ETags Off
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset ETag
</ifModule>
FileETag None
# END Turn ETags Off

# BEGIN Remove Last-Modified Header
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset Last-Modified
</ifModule>
# END Remove Last-Modified Header
```

(taken from [here](http://www.boonex.com/forums/topic/Need-for-Speed-.htm))

I'm using Chrome to test and I've noticed that the CSS files that should be cached, really are not cached:

[image]

The request header for one random CSS file is:

```
Accept:text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:es-ES,es;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:sua_language=en; keep=0; user=0; PHPSESSID=hn5gt5nb1j4sfq1j6m40un3it6; language=es
Host:podo.com
If-Modified-Since:Tue, 01 Nov 2011 17:20:59 GMT
Referer:http://podo.com/sheet?id=48
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.53 Safari/534.30
```

and the response is:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=86400, public
Connection:Keep-Alive
Date:Tue, 28 Feb 2012 17:50:04 GMT
Expires:Wed, 29 Feb 2012 17:50:04 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
Server:Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.2.10
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

I also have the following piece of code that is executed before any JS file:

```
// Set document header
header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8');

$expires = ONE_DAY;
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: maxage=".$expires);
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$expires) . ' GMT');
```

and I have noticed that if I comment these lines and reload the page (not by pressing F5, using navigation buttons), some (not all) Javascript files has the same behaviour than the CSS files (are forced to reload).

What's happening? Why the CSS files are never cached? And why the JS files are sometimes cached, sometimes not?

**UPDATE**: I've discovered that if I comment the line <ifModule mod_expires.c> and it corresponding closing tag, everything works as expected, it is, CSS files are not requested (as happens with JS files). The question now is: why?

**UPDATE 2**: Response header when a CSS files is received first time (200 response):

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:max-age=86400, public
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:1633
Content-Type:text/css
Date:Thu, 01 Mar 2012 16:01:53 GMT
Expires:Fri, 02 Mar 2012 16:01:53 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
Server:Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.2.10
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

Request header is identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact they *are* cached. The important thing to note here is this line of the request:

```
If-Modified-Since: Tue, 01 Nov 2011 17:20:59 GMT
```

Chrome is asking for the server to send a new copy of the file *if and only if* it has been modified since `Tue, 01 Nov 2011 17:20:59 GMT`.

The expected response here would be one of two things: If the file has been modified, the server should return the new version in the body of the response with a `200 OK` response code. If the file has not been modified, the server should give a `304 Not Modified` response and the body of the response will be empty - if you look at the response code showed in the console, you will see that this is what is happening.

For more information, see [this section](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.25) and [this section](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.5) of RFC2616.

*Footnote*: what is interesting, I have not previously observed and I cannot readily explain is why `private` resources are used with rechecking the server, and `public` resources are not. At least, this is what I assume is happening based on the fact that your JS files are used straight from the cache and your CSS files are not.

Comment: "the body of the response will be empty". I don't know if you are refering to what Chrome shows on the "Content" tab. Here it shows the full content of the file. But it also shows the same for the *(from cache)* files.. The point is why some files are "rechecked" and other files not? My intention was to avoid any rechecking.

Also I have tried to change "public" and "private" types without any change.

Comment: I am going to do some playing around with this tomorrow and see if I can come up with a definitive answer. I think it is likely to be related to the `private`/`public` directives, try clearing your browser cache and setting both CSS/JS to `private` to see if this get's rid of the additional requests.

Comment: I have tested all combination without success, no changes. Have you seen my update?

Comment: That is interesting - are you saying you comment out the whole section, or just comment out the lines that make it conditional? Also, is it possible for you to execute the same set of PHP `header()`s before serving CSS (for testing) and post the new response headers here?

Comment: Just commented the lines that make it conditional. What test you need I do? I don't understand what do you want to test..

Comment: You say `I also have the following piece of code that is executed before any JS file` - can you do the same for CSS? This is what I want you to test, since your JS files are not having the problem (so far as I can see from your screenshot). Also, you say that commenting the lines fixes the problem - can you add the headers when you originally receive the file into the browser, so we can compare against when it does not work?

Comment: Ok, I have tested it (generate a CSS header like JS files) and with this the file is cached exactly the same way as the JS files. So this makes me think that the problem is with the .htaccess file, for some reason is not changing the file headers. Also I have made a new update (2) to show you the original header received.